# How to access all HTML5 localstorage regardless of domain? (NOT subdomain-related)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to write a memory-aide script for myself that automatically and permanently saves some information from pages that meet certain conditions. I was told HTML5 was the way to do it with Javascript (this being the only web scripting language I have any acquaintance with). However, HTML5 local storage saves information on a per-domain basis.

All the questions/answers I have found are either about 1) retrieving all localstorage keys for a domain or 2) website owners creating workarounds for subdomain/www-related shenanigans. I just want **every single localstorage key, across *all* domains, that bears a particular prefix**.

I thought about fetching the information directly from the file in which the browser actually keeps the localstorage stuff, but I opened it up in Notepad++ and it was an unreadable mess in which I could see neither rhyme nor reason (nor convenient linebreaks...)

Is there any way to retrieve the information I want?

Comment: Local storage is for web applications to store data locally within the user's browser. It sounds like you want something like a browser extension that could interact with a REST API or something to write information to a permanent store, but I don't think browser local storage is going to provide the features for the use case you're looking for.

What is the use case for the memory-aide script?

Comment: you probably need to look at creating a browser extension. Accessing it through a webpage won't work for security reasons

Comment: @Fred: I'm trying to log articles/blog posts I read that contain certain title or URL keywords (and have a button for adding other information if I do remember)

Comment: @barleycorn ok makes sense, you'd need to implement this as a browser extension.

Comment: @Fred: I see. I remember seeing that Firefox extensions use Javascript as well, and it seems the same for Chrome. But being a browser extension will... give access to the data, is it?